# should I use transaction with command ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am calling few stored procedures (functions in postgresql) using `ExecuteNonQuery` inside C# transaction,My SPs looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.setuserstatus(
    par_userid integer,
    par_status character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.user
    SET status = par_status
        WHERE userid = par_userid;

END;
$BODY$;
```

So to call this function what should be the best practice? is below code enough or I should use this inside transaction and use commit and rollback? please suggest?

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync(ct);
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("irnutil.setcrdsstatusforapmaccount", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ApmAccountIdParameterName, accountId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(CrdsStatusParameterName, crdsStatus.ToString());
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(ct);
                }
            }
```

Also, the Npgsql documentations says "However, for maximum portability it's recommended to set the transaction on your commands.", is that mean we should use transaction here?
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/transactions.html

Comment: A transaction is only really necessary if you're running more than one query and you need the data to be in a consistent state when they finish - e.g. if it would cause a problem if one query failed while the others succeeded. Your code doesn't appear to be doing that.

Comment: Last I checked, the `CommandType.StoredProcedure` doesn't work the way you might expect.  Perhaps that's been changed with the latest Npgsql.  The simple way to do it is to use "select" for a function or "call" for a stored procedure, and then all works fine without declaring the CommandType property.

Comment: yes It changed, it is not causing any issue and you can use either way.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

The general idea of transaction is - **A unit of work that is performed against a Database.**

However, you will not want to use a transaction over *select queries*.

for Example:

```
select * from some table where condition = {condition}
```

Will not be a candidate for a proper transaction block.

**Your example of update, is a good candidate.**

Now comes the question, ***whether I should use it at code level or Database level***?

The answer is again a question - What do you want to achieve?

---

- **If you perform it Database level**, you will lose your ability to log errors. Yes, the transaction, if executed correctly to satisfy
  your conditions will rollback the operation but you will have no
  further details, meaning that you will have to use a profiler to
  determine the cause for failure. On the other hand, Your transaction
  will be safe and secured from the 'outside world' - If the chance
  happen and someone changes your code or an harmful attack is taking
  place, they will not be able to change the transaction and the data
  will be safer.
- **If you perform it code level**, You will be able to log the exception and review the cause for failure, it will be easier to
  handle programatically however - It will be exposed to code changes
  and possible malware attacks as I mentioned above.
- **A deadlock situation may occur during the execution of a transaction**, meaning that if you execute a block of sql wrapped in transaction, you cannot execute it again until the transaction finished it's job or, you will encounter a dead lock and throw an exception. In that case it is recommended to create a queue to monitor your calls to the transaction and check whether you are clear to make another execution or not.

Again - this is all your decision according to your needs.

Comment: So will it be fine for long running transactions? like in my scenario, I have few jobs calling DB and may take more than 10mins, in that case if I use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` inside transaction, will it block other transaction for that time? as documentation saying PG execute one transaction at a time.

Comment: Edited to answer